# Attached property declaration

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, attached-properties

I have created an attached property to be added to UserControls. This attached property requires a binding, and this binding requires a converter.

As the resources are set after the UserControl declaration I'm looking a way to declare the attached property after the resource creation. How can I do that?

An example, if I define a background as a static resource I cannot set the background on the control creation but after the resources creation:

```
<UserControl ...
             ...
             ...>

<UserControl.Resources>
    background color declared
</UserControl.Resrouces>

<UserControl.Background>
    usage of the StaticResource here is valid.
</UserControl.Background>
```

So I want to the same with an attached property that I woudl normaly define as:

```
<UserControl xx:MyAttachedProperty.Bla="{Binding A}" >
```

But as I need a converter I want to specify it after the resources.

Hope it's clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your`Converter` as a resource one hierarchy up either as a part of `Window` or `App`and than you can use it just like you intended to.

Moreover moving common resources up to App level give you advantage of `re-usability` which different User controls can share. Move your converter to `App.xaml` -

```
<App.Resources>
  <!-- Your converter here -->
</App.Resources>
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that Resources where shared that way. Nice thing to know. I'm going to check it. Anyway, do you know if I can declare the attached property like <UserControl.TheAttachedProperty> somehow? Because this converter is specific of the view and it's not going to be reused for sure.

Comment: @SoMoS if you're only using the property on the UserControl why don't you just make it a normal DP. That way you can get the behavior you want as well and it's clear enough to say its a property only for that UserControl

Comment: Its the converter the one being used only on the user control. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `ResourceDictionary`.

Just add it in the solution explorer with `Add -> Resource dictionary`

Declare your `Converter` there like

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibility" />

</ResourceDictionary>
```

In your `XAML`, you can use it like

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now you can use your `Converter` anywhere where you have your `Resource Dictionary`

If you only need your `Converter` in your `UserControl` (as you mentioned in the Comment above), then you can still declare it like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConverter" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I just used `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` for the example, but it is easy to use your own converter there.

Comment: Not at all. I cannot use anything declared into that dictionary before calling Window.Resources and that's exactly the problem I have.

Comment: There are two steps. Declare it in the dictionary, then in window.resources add that dictionary and you can use it.

Comment: The resource dictionary is a good way of declaring common resources that can be reused easily across an application.